# MariaDB CAST OR CONVERT Function is not work

Tags: type-conversion, mariadb

my table has a varchar(64) column ,when i try to convert it to char(36), it not work.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT('00edff66-3ef4-4447-8319-fc8eb45776ab',CHAR(36)) AS A,
CAST('00edff66-3ef4-4447-8319-fc8eb45776ab' AS CHAR(36)) as B
```

this is desc result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's like this because it is derived from MySQL where there was no CAST AS VARCHAR option. In MySQL there was only CAST AS CHAR which was producing VARCHAR. Here are what the supported options were in MySQL 5.6:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

See they explicitly mention that "*No padding occurs for values shorter than N characters*". Later MariaDB started adding CAST AS VARCHAR only to make it more cross-platform compatible with systems like Oracle, Postgre, MSSQL, etc.:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11283

But still CAST AS CHAR and CAST AS VARCHAR is the same. And I guess it should be the same. Why do you need the fixed length datatype in RAM? It should matter only when you store it.

For example if you have a table with CHAR datatype:

```
    CREATE TABLE tbltest(col CHAR(10));
```

and you insert casted as VARCHAR data for example:

```
    INSERT INTO tbltest(col) VALUES(CAST('test' AS VARCHAR(5)));
```

it will be stored as CHAR(10) datatype. Because that's what the table uses.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.Because this column in my table is varchar ,but the definition of the class in my program is Guid.My program is also compatible with sqlserver,this  column in sqlserver is defined as uniqueidentifier.
I don't want to make too many changes to the program...

Comment: The table structure in mariadb is not defined by me, so I am looking for a way to convert the data type when querying in SQL

Comment: I really do not understand what you exactly mean here. The GUID datatype is BINARY(16).